# Android - Grouping layouts and views

Tags: android-layout, android

I need some advice on how to best achieve a UI in Android.

I'd like to have a list of containers. Each container has 7 items laid out as shown below. Items 5-7 are sub-containers that have two text elements.

I'm thinking a `LinearLayout` that contains a list of `RelativeLayouts`. That much is clear. As for how to lay out elements within the `RelativeLayout`, I'm not so sure.

Any advice on how to slice it? What's the most effective way to group the layouts and views together?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a ListView with an adapter that inflates custom rows.

For the rows I personally would use 1 parent RelativeLayout, and just align all of my children within it directly. But it could be achieved with some LinearLayouts instead if you prefer those.

Not only will building it this way make it fairly easy to make the layouts it will also give you the opportunity to make the List dynamic if you every have a need to populate it with different or more data (rows)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code yet and I know it looks kind of cluttered but off the top of my head this is something I would personally try since I once wrote a custom ListView with an almost similar layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView> //position at top
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing...
</TextView>
<TableLayout> //stretchcolumns = 2 && position at bottom
    <TableRow>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView>
                Lorem Ipsum //position at top
            </TextView>
            <ImageView>
                icon    //position to left
            </ImageView>
            <TextView>
                Lorem Ipsum //position to right
            </TextView>
        <RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TableLayout> //stretchcolumns = 3
            <TableRow> //give all children a weight of 1
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView>
                        1234 //position at top
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView>
                        Lorem Ipsum //position at bottom
                    </TextView>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView>
                        1234 //position at top
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView>
                        Lorem Ipsum //position at bottom
                    </TextView>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView>
                        1234 //position at top
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView>
                        Lorem Ipsum //position at bottom
                    </TextView>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), an overview of it is presented here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

It was introduced in API level 14 (Android 4.0) but a backport compatible down to API level 7 is available as part of the Android support library.